# Intercept submit() calls on a form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension and I would like to intercept all calls to a form's submit method, and selectively allow/disallow them.

It appears the form onsubmit event is only fired when a form's submit button is clicked, and not when submit() is called. So this is not going to help.

I was thinking I could use the form's prototype to hack my own submit method in there, is that possible?

Comment: `window.HTMLFormElement.prototype.oldsubmit = window.HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit; window.HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function(){//your code. if allow: this.oldsubmit()}`

Comment: Why not take a look at jQuery's source to see how they catch the submit action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about altering the prototype, but you can definitely overwrite the submit function on the form object itself (this happens often when designers decide to give submit buttons a name="submit" attribute for no apparent reason).

So, you could just do a node query to find all the forms, and replace each one's submit property with your own wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's sandboxing prevents this from working. If you do this from a content script, the page will still see the original submit() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.someform.submitOrig = document.someform.submit;

document.someform.submit = function() {

        this.onsubmit();

        this.submitOrig();

};
```

This works, thanks GGG